# How to trigger Spring boot form submission by clicking on an li element?

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, thymeleaf

I have a side bar for my user profile page which has two items for 1) Updating the information and 2) showing the reviews that the user has already written.
The first item works perfectly (as it includes a `form` and has a `submit` button). But for the second one, I have no idea. The goal is that when I click on `My Reviews`, a method from the controller class is called, the reviews of the user are extracted from the database and the results are shown on the right side of the page.
As I don't have a `submit` button or a `form` for the second item, I don't know how I can implement it.
Here is my code:

```
        <div class="module-inner">
                    <div class="side-bar">                      
                        <nav class="side-menu">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#profile">Profile</li>
                                    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#review">My
                                            Reviews</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>

                    <div class="content-panel">
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div id="profile" class="tab-pane fade">
                                    <form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/edit_profile}">                                         <fieldset class="fieldset">
                                            <h3 class="fieldset-title">Personal Info</h3>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">User
                                                    Name</label>
                                                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                                        th:disabled="${currentUser.email}"
                                                        th:value="${currentUser.email}">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">First
                                                    Name</label>
                                                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                    <input name="firstname" type="text" class="form-control"
                                                        th:value="${currentUser.firstname}">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Last
                                                    Name</label>
                                                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                    <input name="lastname" type="text" class="form-control"
                                                        th:value="${currentUser.lastname}">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>

                                        <hr>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-push-2 col-sm-push-3 col-xs-push-0">
                                                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
                                                    value="Update Profile">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>

                                <div id="review" class="tab-pane fade">
                                    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
                                    <p>You have no reviews yet.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/findUserReviews", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView findUserReviews() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
    ..
    modelAndView.addObject("reviews", reviewRepository.findUserRevies());

    modelAndView.setViewName("profile");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

I use the following technologies: `Spring boot`, `Hibernate` and `Thymeleaf`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Final update: The provided code in the accepted answer works, provided that I don't return a `ModelAndView` but a `List<Review>`.

Comment: Have you tried to use javascript and Ajax calls ?

Comment: @SebastianI. Could you please explain a bit more. With Ajax, I haven't tried but I tried with javascript and I couldn't get it worked. If you could write your idea as pseudo-code, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Ajax calls you can call the controller endpoints using javascript. One ajax call looks like this :

```
function getReviews() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/users/findUserReviews", //example
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {
        //do something with this JSON
        fillReviews(data);
    }
});
}
```

Now you can use this function as an `on-click` event for your button. And the `fillReviews()` is a function that gets the element with id="review" from the jsp page and create the list tree with the fetched data.

```
function fillReviews(data) {
  var reviewDiv= document.getElementById('review');
  var reviewList = document.createElement('ul');
  for ( var i=0 ; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      var reviewListItem = createListItem(data[i]);
      reviewList.appendChild(reviewListItem);
    }
  reviewDiv.appendChild(reviewList);
}
```

And `createListItem(data[i])` could look like this:

```
function createListItem(data)
{
  var listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.innerHTML = data["reviewName"]; // for example ..
  return listItem;
}
```

And now all you have to do is to call `getReviews()` here :

```
<button onclick="getReviews()"/>
```

**EDIT** : The "data" from the ajax call is a JSON. So the "/users/findUserReviews" should return a `List<Review>` for example. And there is no need to change your original "/findUserReviews" endpoint. This was only an example, you can create a new endpoint in your controller which returns a list.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm actually not using jsp, but simple html pages. With your code I can access the method and when I print something out in the controller method, it works. But I can't have the results back on my html page. Do you have any idea in that case?

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(data)` in the *success* function code block from the ajax call?

Comment: Maybe there is no data and that is why the list is not getting created.

Comment: I exactly tried that and nothing is printed with log(data) in the success function, but when I print out the result in the control method to the console, the list is not empty.

Comment: Are you sure the *url* is correct? This isn't a behaviour that should happen if everything is configured right. Do you have the return type set to *List<>* or *Set<>* for the controller method you're trying to fetch data from ?

Comment: In the controller I have this section: 
List<Review> resultReviews = reviewRepository.findByUser(user);
  List<Review> list2 = new ArrayList<Review>(resultReviews);
and when I print out the list2 in a for loop, it works and I can see the output. But in the fillReviews function that you have written, I have "console.log("test in output") ;" as the first line and nothing is printed out.

Comment: Just to be sure I've got your problem right: the list2 is printed in the console when you're pressing the button from the html page?

Comment: Exactly. When I click the button on the html page, I get the list2 printed out from the controller method.

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question, but I am wondering where "data" is defined. The success function in your ajax code has an input called "data". Shouldn't it be somewhere defined?

Comment: No, it's not a stupid question, but no, the `data` shouldn't be defined anywhere. What you're doing here is **CREATING** a new function, not calling it (in JS you don't need to specify the parameters' type). In case of success, this function is called and the parameters are mapped from the success response. [Here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you can read more about ajax.

Comment: But now I'm very curious about your problem because I've created a new project with a basic controller and the same ajax call and everything works fine. Please let me now if you would like to continue our conversation in a separate chat room and maybe offer some more details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209611/discussion-between-user1419243-and-sebastian-i).